# How to do Automatic Rollback using Liquiabse + Jenkins + EKS + Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, jenkins, liquibase, amazon-eks, rollback

Its been a while , i am trying to implement the automatic roll back with the liquibase changes.

**Ex :** when we deploy our spring boot application which contains liquiabse , it creates the changelog. Now lets assume we are tagging the changesets which is same as our docker image tag.
now if i wanna to revert the changes with previous docker i can deploy the specific docker image by its tag but the changelog also should be reverted / rolled back

may i know is there anyone out there who developed/implemented this logic or if any thought process also would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

SpringBoot doesn't have rollback capability built in, so you will have to drive it from something separate.

One option would be to create custom code in your SpringBoot application that calls the Liquibase APIs to do the rollback and use a SpringBoot profile to trigger it.

Alternatively, you could automate it outside SpringBoot, just using the Docker CLI to call the Liquibase CLI.